# CURLOPT_READFUNCTION - how to distinct error from valid written bytes

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have a question regarding the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION function in libcurl.

The documentation mentions that the callback should return the number
of bytes that were written to the byte array -

- for example if CURL asked to write 100 bytes and my file contains 42 so I'll write 42 bytes and return 42.
- But if i have some kind of error i should return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT - it's enum number is also 42.

Someone have a clue about how curl will distinguish between the two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURL_READFUNC_ABORT` is 0x10000000 which is a value you cannot return as "number of bytes read" since the buffer will never be that large. Thus, your hypothetical situation cannot occur in the real world.

The libcurl code first checks if the value is `CURL_READFUNC_ABORT` which causes a `CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK` return code, or if the value is unaligned to what passed in it will return `CURLE_READ_ERROR`.

Comment: Thanks ! Actually you right, that will not happen in the real world.